# Responsive website on different android devices like tablets and mobiles with a clear image quality?

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview to display website URL. Actually, that website contains text and images. When I open my app, automatically url get accessed and can get into that website directly. So user can be able to click anything which is in home screen (On website) to see their products. This is what have done a program using Webview.

I am able to see that website through android app on samsung mobile device through programmatically. But not able to see a clear website on different android devices like tablet and another mobile devices through APK. Is there any other solution?

Image is not getting fitted into a webview properly when I test it on different android devices like tablets.

[image: I am using this Image]

How those websites will work with webview (With an Image and text alignment which is already built in a website using Bootstrap)?

My code is:

```
wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    String url="http://192.169.11.15/CustomerCentric";
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl(url);
}

   private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In Xml,

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

In emulator, i could be able to see output like this which is not at all clear!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Apply `Boot Strap` to your website. Responsible for mobile devices

Comment: @MD It is working in Windows mobile. I do not know windows development. Anyways, thank you will try to apply Boot Strap to website.

Comment: Also i think it's working fine in iOS but the case in `Android` it's different.

Comment: @MD - How to work in Android then? Actually, bootstrap has been applied to Website. All the Images are working fine but this header image is not clear in home screen. I do not know what is the reason?

Comment: clear the cache when you start the web-view and then load the url.also there can be problem with the website behaviour. try accessing that website in the desktop chrome with your mobile resolution to see whether this is an android issue or the website issue.

Comment: @ammar shahid - Ok, will try now. Thanks!

Comment: @MD - This website is working well in samsung mobile device but not working in tablet. I mean, the same image problem which I have said in above!

Comment: @ammar shahid - This website is working well in samsung mobile device but not working in tablet. I mean, the same image problem which I have said in above!

Comment: did you tried it in desktop browser ?

Comment: In desktop browser, its looking good. Only in tablet is not working. Image is not good. So, how should I solve it in tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is,

Step 1: In HTML, height should be set as an auto-fit or in pixels instead of percent. So that website url may support for all different android devices using Webview. Hence, Webview engine has no advance feature. I have used older webkit engine.

Step 2: If you do not set heights in HTML as i mentioned above, then can use chromium webview. It has advanced features. For an example, if you did not set heights in html as a auto-fit or in pixels then automatically chromium webview will scale the height. From above 4.4, this chromium webview has been designed. If you do not give any heights also, this chromium webview will automatically sets height in pixels. So that websites are displaying properly on different android devices including tablets and mobiles.

These are the reasons - So this website has worked only in samsung mobile device which is 4.4 version but in other devices like tablets and mobiles (lower versions) doesn't support it. So image quality was not good!